# How to kill a process generated through windows cmd line using c#?

Tags: c#, windows, process, adb, android-logcat

I have an windows application in C# which gets Android Logs (LOGCAT) and Android BugReport (BugReport).

To get these logs, i am using bat files with commands like.
For Bugreport,

```
adb bugreport >>C:\User\Desktop\androidUser\bugrep%dt%_%tm%.txt
```

For LogCat,

```
 adb logcat -long V >>C:\User\Desktop\androidUser\LogCat%dt%_%tm%.txt
```

*dt and tm are timestamps.*

I can run both of this commands at one (With two different buttons in aspx webpage) but if i want to stop only one of them then the problem arise.

The problem is that i can't kill the process using process name as its same for the both tasks. Another thing that i have tried is save the process id while executing the command and kill it but the pid associated while running the task is of cmd, so adb task keeps keeps running and is not killed as i wished.

Comment: Well, how *can* you distinguish between the two? Unless you have a way to do that, you're screwed :) Processes run from cmd are processes like any other. Why are you running them through cmd in the first place, if you want to track them in the future?

Comment: Hey @Luaan,
I distuingish by monitioring them in Taskmanager of Windows. 
I am getting these logs form a webpage and, for getting buttons i run .bat files with above instructions. So i need to use cmd.

Any other alternative for cmd in this case?

Comment: Look into `Process` and `ProcessStartInfo` classes. You can launch applications with arguments which seems to be all you are doing. Can't you sidestep the need of .bat files altoghether? That would make tracking each process independently trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Look into [`Process`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`ProcessStartInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) classes. You can launch applications with arguments which seems to be all you are doing. Can't you sidestep the need of .bat files altoghether? That would make tracking each process independently trivial.

Something along the following lines:

```
var dt = ....
var tm = ....
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("adb", $"bugreport >>C:\\User\\Desktop\\androidUser\\bugrep{dt}_{tm}.txt");
var bugReportingProcess = Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Sometimes, arguments are only parsed correctly if quoted:

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("adb", $"\"bugreport >>C:\\User\\Desktop\\androidUser\\bugrep{dt}_{tm}.txt\"");
```

And now killing the correct process is easy:

```
if (!bugReportingProcess.HasExited) bugReportingProcess.Kill();
```

Comment: Will try it and I will let you know, but sounds much better

Comment: Tried to use it, it correctly launches adb.exe but i am having trouble while passing the above arguments.

Still digging on it! :(